# Need to build N-level Tree Structure Menu for Custom LMS using php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic, treeview

Can any body please help me with indexing of parent-child Hierarchy Menu like

Basically, iam creating a personal lms.

```
Main (K-12,NCERT)
->Class (Class 3,Class 4,Class 5)
->Subject (Physics,Chemistry)
->Units (Unit 1,Unit 2)
->Chapter (Chap 1, Chap 2)
->Topic (Topic 1, Topic 2)
->Sub Topic (Sub Top 1, Sub Top 2)
->Sub Sub Topic (Sub Sub Top 1, Sub Sub Top 2)
```

every topic have its own title and contents(text,swf,quality check status)

---

```
- NCERT   
       Class 5   
       Class 6
       Class 6_Physics
         Class 6_Physics_Unit 4
           Class 6_Physics_Unit 4_Chapter 1
           Class 6_Physics_Unit 4_Chapter 2
             Class 6_Physics_Unit 4_Chapter 2_Topic 1
             Class 6_Physics_Unit 4_Chapter 2_Topic 2
             Class 6_Physics_Unit 4_Chapter 2_Topic 3
                --Class 6_Physics_Unit 4_Chapter 2_Topic 3_Sub Topic 1
             Class 6_Physics_Unit 4_Chapter 2_Topic 4
           Chapter 3
         Unit 5
       Class 6_Chemistry
       Class 6_Biology   Class 7   Class 8
       Class 8_Physics
         Class 8_Physics_Unit 1
       Class 8_ Chemistry
       Class 8_Biology
         Class 8_Biology_Unit 4
         Class 8_Biology_Unit 5
```

---

```
1
2
3
3.1
3.1.1
3.1.1.1
3.1.1.1.1
3.2
3.3
4
5
...
...
n
```

Thanks
Seyed

Comment: And your concrete problem is?

Comment: What is the better way to do it?

Comment: It's better to read for persons with limited sight if you increase the font-size for example ;) - secret tip: The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) has some general info about what your question should contain so others can actually answer to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking about the best DB schema, then create a topic table like so:

```
|COLUMN NAME    |DATA TYPE
|---------------|-----------------------------------------------------
|id             | unsigned int, auto-increment, Primary Key, not null
|parent_id      | unsigned int, not null
|title          | varchar(size-as-appropriate)
| ...           |  ... and so on
```

So each record has a unique `id`.  If `parent_id` is `0` then it is a top-level item, otherwise it is a child of whatever record has an `id` equal to the given `parent_id`.

The queries to find children/parents should be quite easy to figure out.

If you want to use MySQL for serious stuff, then I suggest you do some research into relational database design and [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: Iam using the same structure only. But if my menu grows, it hard to map the parent id using drop-down select box. Any suggestion to make it easier to add child and parent effectively.

Comment: " it hard to map the parent id using drop-down select box" - why?  What code are you using to do this already?  A simple `select * from topic where parent_id=x` should be quite straight-forward